# existing fuzzysort.js like sort library for dot net

Tags: .net, .net-core

Basically I've used [this](https://github.com/farzher/fuzzysort) fuzzy sort library before in javascript, and I'd like similar functionality in .NET.

It seems like a pretty basic thing, and I would expect it to exist in the .NET world but I've struggled to find anything like it.

I came across SimMetrics.Net which may support a similar algorithm but the documentation is poor so I'm not sure.  A simple Levenstein distance is not going to work for me.  For example, see how searching for 'Christmas' behaves on the steam_games data set [here](https://rawgit.com/farzher/fuzzysort/master/test.html).

**Please list facts of libraries you know that can accomplish fuzzy sorting in .NET.**

Comment: We need more information on how you are going to use this. Are you using this on a website? Are you using this on windows forms? WPF? I am not sure what you are asking.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish and post a reproduceable example of the code you have tried.

Comment: By the way if you plan to use this on a website then why not just use fuzzy sort?

Comment: I have a search query and I want to compare the query to a collection of strings and get a rank for how similar they are.  
I wish I could give a more concrete requirement, but I'm just looking for something that feels right, and when I used fuzzysort.js in the past it gave me the sort of scores I was looking for.   I just googled "fuzzy sort javascript " or something and found that.  Doing a similar search with .net isn't yielding me anything I really like so far.

Comment: In this case i'm sorting things on the server before returning to the client, and the backend is developed in c#.

Comment: well there is https://github.com/JakeBayer/FuzzySharp

Comment: Also there is https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5165898/FuzzySortLib-A-New-Method-for-Sorting-Data-Using-F

Comment: FuzzySharp looks interesting, thank you.  Seems like that would have come up in my search results...